# ORA-00902 in Oracle Application Testing Suite

Tags: sql, oracle, testing, oracle11g, automated-tests

Hey guys I'm running this Script on OATS and it's showing the ORA-00902: invalid datatype error, but I run the same exact Query on my Oracle DB and it brings me the results as shown on the attached images, does anybody know why this might be happening?

```
select FISCAL_YEAR,ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,LEDGER,ACCOUNT,DEPTID,CLASS_FLD,
sum(POSTED_BASE_AMT), SUM( POSTED_TRAN_AMT) from sysadm.ps_ledger A
where FISCAL_YEAR = '2018'
AND LEDGER IN ('REPORT','LOCAL','DREPORT','DLOCAL','CREPORT','CLOCAL')
and EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM sysadm.PSTREELEAF G
where G.tree_name='STATUTORY_ACCT'
    and G.setid='SHARE'
    and G.effdt= to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd') 
   and (G.TREE_NODE_NUM BETWEEN 914962101 AND 1237889900
   )
   and A.ACCOUNT = G.RANGE_FROM)
and EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM sysadm.PSTREELEAF G
where G.tree_name='RPT_DEPT_BL'
    and G.setid='SHARE'
    and G.effdt= to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd')
   and (G.TREE_NODE_NUM BETWEEN 1684955749 AND 1999972344
   )
   and A.DEPTID = G.RANGE_FROM)
group by FISCAL_YEAR,ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,LEDGER,ACCOUNT,DEPTID,CLASS_FLD
```

[image]

[image]